# Replay timer based data though python websocket

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

Currently I am working on a IoT Mockup Client, which reads in a couple of real-world timeseries data CSVs and "replays" them based on their timestamp and the system clock (`threading` module).

So basically I have a Pandas Dataframe which holds all the old data and a timer tick handler function which extracts the corresponding rows from it to yield them to any data sink.

This works perfectly if my timer-tick-handler uses `requests.post(..` then to post simply a text body gathered from `df[...<current-timeslice-filer>...].to_csv()`.

Now I want to stream this data to a server api, therefore we decided to transmit data via Websockets rather than HTTP-REST. There things start to get tricky. The [`websockets`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module relies heavily on `asyncio` which needs its own event loop. As my timer is already kind of an event loop (based on `threading.timer`) and I must admit that I don't fully understand the concepts around asyncio, I think that this doesn't quite fit together.

At least I do not know how to integrate the websocket.send() method into my handler method so that it is run inside the asyncio event loop.

DataFrame.to_csv(... can be given a file handler `file_or_buf`, and I would appreciate it more to use a websocket just like a file handler and provide it here, to flush my data through.

- Is there another websocket implementation in python which uses this paradigm?
- Can `websockets` module be used to achieve this? Am I just getting it wrong?
- Do I have to implement my time interval based data sending handler also with asyncio, so that both is running inside the event loop?

*EDIT what I have so far...*

Thats my timer class which calls method `do()` every `interval` seconds

```py
from threading import Thread,Event

class TimeTicker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval=1):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.stopped = Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(self.interval):
            self.do()

    def do(self):
        print('tick')

    def get_stopflag(self):
        return self.stopped
```

Now the basic snippet for using `websockets` and `asyncio` is...

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(thread.stream())
        r = await websocket.recv()
        print(r)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

I already tried to make my `do()` method `async` but I am not able to initialize my `TimeTicker` class inside the asyncio event loop, so that method calls are 'awaited'

To keep things clear, I would like to initialize the websocket connection outside the TimeTicker object (it should only provide timeseries data every second and pass it to `websocket.send()`. Nevertheless I am not sure where this pass of data should happen then. There might also be a better solution of my TimeTicker class to `yield` data every second instead of just calling a method. Anyway I´d like to get advice on this.

Hint: TimeTicker is only a superclass on my datasource class which actually holds the pandas dataframe with approx. 200.000 rows of timeseries data read from CSV as a reservoir to send.

**Solution: based on @wowkin2 's answer** my TimeTicker Class is now realized with asyncio alone...

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


class TimeTicker:
    is_stopped = False

    def __new__(cls, _loop, _uri, interval=1):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.interval = interval
        instance.uri = _uri
        instance.task = _loop.create_task(instance.run())
        return instance.task

    async def run(self):
        async with websockets.connect(self.uri) as self.ws:
            while True:
                await self.do()
                await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)

    async def do(self):
        message = 'ping'
        await self.ws.send(message)
        r = await self.ws.recv()
        print(r)

    def stop(self):
        self.task.cancel()
        self.is_stopped = True

uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org"
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = TimeTicker(loop, uri, interval=5)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Comment: Every second we get data (from where?) and then send it to a web socket?

Comment: Is `TimeTicker.do` that gets the data that we need to send through the web socket?

Comment: no, because then it.would create a new Connection to the websocket every time... I already tried to Connect outside and Pass the Connection to the function, but that's outside of the Loop then and again "Not awaited"

Comment: @Hadus yes, the dataframe is then available in the object via self.data

Comment: It would be so much easier if you didn't use threading to wait before calls. You can wait inside of an async event loop too. For example after you got the response from the web-socket you calculate how much you need to wait before contacting the web-socket again. This way you could use the same connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need threading modules if you are using asyncio.

Here is an example how to do something periodically using asyncio.
The only thing - you'll need to have variable with always open connection without context manager.

```
import asyncio


class TimeTicker:
    is_stopped = False

    def __new__(cls, _loop, _ws, interval=1):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.interval = interval
        instance.ws = _ws
        instance.task = _loop.create_task(instance.run())
        return instance.task

    async def run(self):
        while True:
            await self.do()
            await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)

    async def do(self):
        message = 'ping'
        await self.ws.send(message)
        r = await self.ws.recv()
        print(r)

    def stop(self):
        self.task.cancel()
        self.is_stopped = True


uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org"
ws = websockets.connect(uri)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = TimeTicker(loop, ws, interval=5)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Comment: Had to slightly adopt it adding `async with websockets.connect(self.uri) as self.ws:` a line before `while True` so that the websocket connection got initalized. IDK why, but it didn't work to pass the `ws` handler via the constructor. Neat Class constructor pattern btw, didn't know that. This helps me a lot getting my stuff running now! Thank you very much!